# API call in canactivate method in Angular

Tags: angular

I am using `canActivate` using `guards` in Angular. I want to check if the user is authenticated and based on the result protect the route. 
There are two types of users: `Type1` and `Type2`, so user can be either authenticated with `Type1`, `Type2` or `unauthenticated`.
The following `guard` is for `Type1` user.

Here is my code:

```
constructor(private authservice: AuthService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){}
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean{

        const self = this;
        const expectedType = "type1";

        this.authservice.isUserAuthenticatedbyType(expectedType).then(
            function(data){
                if(data === false){
                    console.log(data);
                    self.router.navigate(['/'], {relativeTo: self.route});
                }
                return data;
            },
            function(error){
                self.router.navigate(['/']);
                return false;
            }
        );
        return false;
    }
```

The problem is I make an API call to validate if the user is authenticated and `return false;` is executed before the result from the API. So, momentarily I see a different page and then it is routed to the correct page. How can I fix this, I do not want to return false or true before the API call, but not doing that gives an error.

I also tried the following:

```
return this.authservice.isUserAuthenticatedbyType(expectedType)
```

But this simply navigates me to the `http://localhost:4200` url in case of `unauthenticated` user.

I have the following route:

```
{ path: "", component: HomeComponent },
```

So, in the above scenario, `HomeComponent` should have been called, but `ngOnInit` of HomeComponent is not getting called.

Comment: Return an `Observable<boolean>`, not a boolean.

Comment: Doing `return this.authservice.isUserAuthenticatedbyType(expectedType)` should work from the look of it

Comment: @user184994 Yes but it is navigating to `http://localhost:4200` but `HomeComponent` ngOnInit is not called where I have some logic to execute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve it like this:

## Angular <= 7.0.0

```js
public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  return this.authservice.isUserAuthenticatedbyType("type1").pipe(
    map(data => {
      if (data === false) {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        return false;
      }

      return !!data;
    }),
    catchError(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      return of(false);
    }),
  );
}
```

## Angular >= 7.1.0

Starting with Angular 7.1.0 (note that it's *not* in 7.0.x), you can also do this instead, which is shorter and more predictable if you have multiple guards:

```js
public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  return this.authservice.isUserAuthenticatedbyType("type1").pipe(
    map(data => data === false ? this.router.parseUrl("/") : !!data)
    catchError(() => this.router.parseUrl("/")),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using Angular 6 and rxjx version `6.2.1` but I get the following error:
Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Promise<boolean>.
Also, can you please explain what I was doing wrong, if possible.

Comment: It sounds like your service method is returning a Promise, not an observable. You can use `fromPromise(this.authservice.isUserAuthenticatedbyType("type1"))` to convert it into an observable on which you can then use `pipe`. What you were doing wrong was that you synchronously returned an answer from the guard but only asynchronously were able to redirect. My solution defers the answer from the guard until the redirect actually happens.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still not able to understand when I was simply returning the following: `return this.authservice.isUserAuthenticatedbyType(expectedType)`, why was I getting redirected to `localhost:4200` and still `HomeComponent` was not getting called?

Comment: Without any redirect, if the guard rejects the navigation, the navigation just fails. There's no automatic redirect to the root route or anything like that. It just rejects the navigation attempt.

Answer (score 7):

You can also try like this:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return new Promise(res => {
        this.authservice.isUserAuthenticatedbyType("type1").subscribe(
            (data) => {
                if (data === true) {
                    res(true);
                } else {
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                    res(false);
                }
            },
            (error) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
                res(false);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `promise` try something like this - main idea is to hold your routing until your `Api` call is done - I had the same issue, I have achieved it by returning `Promise<boolean>`  on my `route` gaurds

```
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean{
    const self = this;
    const expectedType = "type1";
    retrun new Promise(res => {
      this.authservice.isUserAuthenticatedbyType(expectedType).then(
        function (data) {
          if (data === false) {
            console.log(data);
            self.router.navigate(['/'], { relativeTo: self.route });
          }
          res(data);
        },
        function (error) {
          self.router.navigate(['/']);
          res(false);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

This method solved my issue - it waits until the **API** returns data and gives direction to the route

Hope it will work - Happy coding !!